# A simple question

Tags: optics

This is a simple question but it seems to me that both the explanations are acceptable.

Let say the least distance of least distinguished vision is 25 cm.

An object is placed 12.5 cm in front of a plain mirror. Where should my eyes be placed such that I can see the image clearly?

Actually, there are only two options:-

A) My eye should be placed 12.5cm from the mirror.

----[Because object distance = 12.5 cm and image distance = 12.5cm .]

B) My eye should be placed 25cm from the mirror.

----[Because the image is “printed” on the mirror. It is just like looking at a picture on the wall.]

So, which is correct?

Comment: Welcome, Mick. Please modify the title to reflect your question.

Comment: This is not a hm-wk mc type question. (1) A typical question of that type has more than 2 options to choose from. (2) The comments included in [ ] are the author's work on explaining why that option should be chosen. (3) object distance, the virtual image, and the image distance are common terms in optics. Also, the question has been well answered by *fffred and by *Kalantre.

Answer (score 2):

The [virtual image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_mirror) created by the flat mirror is 12.5 cm behind the mirror. Thus, if the [lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_%28anatomy%29) of your eye is making an image of something at a distance 25 cm, you should be placed at 12.5 cm from the mirror so that the total distance to the virtual image is 25 cm.

The image is **not** "printed" on the mirror. If it was, then it would just be like something printed on a piece of paper: no three-dimensional perspective.

Comment: Let just neglect all the Physics temporarily. After placing the object, I just want to see the image clearly. Can't one imagine that the mirror is a piece of paper (ie. a picture) with the image as part of the picture?

Comment: Yes you can imagine that, but that is not reality.

Comment: @Mick One does not simply say "Let just neglect all the Physics temporarily" on physics.se and not just for the cringing grammar. This _is_ **physics**.se

Answer (score 0):

**The rays of light from the image appear to originate from the point $12.5$ cm behind the mirror**.Our brain/eyes and in principle any light sensor processes this as if the **image were an actual object placed behind the mirror**.So I should keep my eyes at least $12.5$ cm from the mirror to see a clear image.